# Type error:Request path contains unescaped characters - npm & cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, proxy

I am trying to use `Apache Cordova` for `Android` apps.
I had installed it with `npm`, but when I type the command `cordova platforms add android`, I have this error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/4.0.0  
TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.  
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:73:11)  
    at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:49:10)  
    at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (C:\Users\Friend\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:117:25)  
    at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (C:\Users\Friend\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:184:41)  
    at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (C:\Users\Friend\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:80:8)  
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)  
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)  
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)  
    at Request.start (C:\Users\Friend\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:594:30)  
    at Request.end (C:\Users\Friend\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:1186:28)
```

I thought it was originating from the proxy, so I set `http-proxy` and `https-proxy` like this:

```
npm config set proxy h t t p://proxydomain:port/
```

And I set registry like this:

```
npm config set registry h t t p://registry.npmjs.org/
```

The error stays the same. I tried to delete the proxy from my network and from `npm`, but the error is still there.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I fixed it! it was a problem with the node version...for all who got the same problem, try to downgrade to v 0.10.29!

Comment: Then please edit your question to make the Node version you were using appear, and then post an answer stating how you solved your issue. You can accept your answer in a couple days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you fixed it yet.
But I had the same problem some days ago.
Just uninstall and reinstall node, I actually have with `node -v` version v0.12.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had upgraded to nodejs 0.12.3 and started having this problem. I then researched and found a fix where I replaced certain files in the tunnel-agent folder. This fix worked but then I started having the same problem again after reinstalling Visual Studio 2013.
I removed node 0.12.3 and then installed 0.10.29 and now it is working again. I got the above error whenever I tried to install a windows platform. So now I am running the latest Cordova version with Node JS 0.10.29. I wonder if I would be able to use a more recent version of node or should I even bother.

Answer (score 0):

From @geisi93 at [ionic-cli github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/321)

> for those who still have problems - propably you have to replace the
>   contents of
>
> C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent
>
> with the contents of with the content of this zip:
>
> https://github.com/mikeal/tunnel-agent
>
> too.